# How to link malloc when compiling with GCC?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, x86-64, nasm

How do I compile/link malloc in assembly when using object files with GCC?
I'm doing something like this:

```
global test
extern malloc
section .text

test:
    mov rdi, 40
    call malloc
    ret
```

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" void*
test(void);

int
main()
{
    std::cout << test() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

How do I compile this?
Doing this:

```sh
nasm -f elf64 test.asm
g++ test.o test.cpp
```

Makes gcc (or ld rather) throw this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: warning: relocation against `malloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `malloc@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```